# use JavaScript so that it uses a closure to return the response

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the JavaScript code below so it uses a closure to return the response

```
(function() {
    function hello(name, age) {
        return name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!"); 
    }

    console.log(hello('John', 33)); 
}();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: This might help you understand [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) better.

Comment: put const myfunc= in front of the parens

Comment: @segFault just edited the question, sorry.

Comment: const hello=(function(name) {return "hello" +name} ) ()

Comment: That is not a closure.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is a [Self-executing Anonymous Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript), not a Closure. In fact there are no closures in your code at all because no variables' scopes cross function boundaries.

If you want to return a value from an SEAF, just add a `return` statement:

```
const message = (function() {
    function hello(name, age) {
        return name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!"; 
    }

    const result = hello('John', 33);
    console.log( result ); 
    return result;
}();
```

If you want to export the `hello` function through the SEAF as a new function without any parameters (because the parameters are captured inside the returned lambda [i.e. an example of Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), then do this:

```
const hello = (function() {

    function hello(name, age) {
        return name + ", who is " + age + " years old, says hi!"; 
    }

    return () => hello('John', 33);
}());

console.log( hello() ); // will print  "John, who is 33 years old, says hi!" to the console.
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should use a closure in the answer is what I was trying to say*

Comment: @tjhunt I think you don't understand what a closure is - or at least you aren't interpreting your task correctly.